# findIndex method gives undefined in ExpressJS server update method

Tags: javascript, express

I want to update the user object in an express js server from an HTTP request. A put request is sent to the server with the user id. I want to extract the user object from the user array using findIndex method but it returns undefined

here is there ExpressJS server

```
const express = require('express');
const BodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors =require('cors');
const User = require('./user');
const PORT = 4000;
const app =express();
const appRoute = express.Router();
const  userarray = [];

app.use(cors());
app.use(BodyParser.json());

app.use('/api/user',appRoute);

app.listen(PORT ,function () {
    console.log("Sever is running on : " + PORT);
});


appRoute.route('/update/:id').put(function (req,res){
    try{

        const index = userarray.findIndex(instance => instance.id === req.param.id);
        userarray[index].firstName = req.body.fname;
        userarray[index].lastName = req.body.lname;
        userarray[index].BirtDay = req.body.date;

        res.status(200).send({message:"User updated"})

    }catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send({message:"Unable to get the users.ERROR:" +e})
    }
});
```

Her is the user model

```
const  User = function(fname,lname,bday,id){

    this.firstname =  fname;
    this.lastname = lname;
    this.Birthday = bday;
    this.ID =id;
}

module.exports = User;`
```

The ID is there in the array list. So the codes work before but I tried it again and it didn't work. I want to know why.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Error can be recreated successfully. By replacing this code

```js
const index = userarray.findIndex(instance => instance.id === req.param.id);
```

By using this code,

```js
const index = userarray.findIndex(instance => instance.id == req.params.id);
```

User can be updated successfully!!

The reason that I found first was, "==" sign can be used to compare strings and numbers but not "===". Second one was, it should be params but not param because it is now deprecated and also, by using params, it will directly look into route parameters. I hope my answer and the explanation is clear to you  !